# 'incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')' error when trying to import numpy in Atom

Tags: python, numpy, atom-editor

(I'm new to programming so sorry if this is missing some details)

I'm trying to run a piece of code in Atom using Hydrogen that uses Numpy but it throws `incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')` whenever I try to import it. I can use Numpy just fine in terminal, but when I try to run the code in Atom it blows up. The error message says this too, but following their instructions did nothing.

```
Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.10 from "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.23.1"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.
```

The environment its supposedly running in is set up with Python 3.9.12 so I don't understand why it says `The Python version is: Python3.10`; I think the issue has something to do with that, and that Hydrogen is running the wrong version of python but I can't figure out why, or if that's even even the problem.

Someone suggested un- and re-installing Numpy but that didn't work.

I'm on a M1 Pro MacBook running Monterey.

Thanks you a lot for any help! I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow you have the python framework intended for computers running intel chips, and the installed numpy can't run on a RISC architecture. Since I don't know how you got that python framework and if more libraries could be incorrectly installed, I'd recommend reinstalling python entirely. So follow these steps:

1. Run `brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies python3`
2. Delete `Python.framework` at `/Library/Frameworks`
3. Run `brew install python3`
4. Install the latest version from python3 using the universal installer form [the official Python releases for Mac OS](https://www.python.org/downloads/macos/)

After that, reinstall numpy and all other packages you need. Let me know if that solves the issue!